# Could not instantiate bean class [multipart.MultipartFile] : Specified class is an interface at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, file-upload

I want to upload a file on my local website, I use Spring and Hibernate (I do not use Maven).

I have done a form :

```
<form class="text-center" action="<c:url value="/createRessource.do"/>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    <h4 class="bleucolor">Titre de la ressource (20 caractères maximum) : </h4>
    <input class="col-lg-4 text-center col-lg-offset-4" type="text" name="titre" maxlength="20"/> <br> <br> <br>
    <h4 class="bleucolor">Description de la ressource (1024 caractères maximum) : </h4>
    <textarea name="description" rows=10 cols=50 maxlength="1024" ></textarea><br><br><br>
    <h4 class="bleucolor"> Pièce jointe :</h4>
    <input class="col-lg-4 text-center col-lg-offset-4" type="file" name="file" /><br><br><br>
    <h4 class="bleucolor"> Tags de la ressource : </h4>
    <c:forEach var="model" items="${sessionScope.tags}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="tagsRessource" value="${model.getIdtag()}" id="${model.getIdtag()}"/>
        <label class="font18" for="${model.getIdtag()}">&thinsp;${model.getLibelle()}&thinsp;</label>
    </c:forEach><br><br><br>
    <input class="text-center avioletbackground rosebtn btn btn-success btn-lg" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I have some input, a title, a description, a file and tags.

I have add

```
<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>
```

in my dispatcher-servlet.xml.

My controller is probably not perfect, because when I start, I only do Controller, DAO and Model, I have forgot all services, but my function "createRessource" is like :

```
public ModelAndView createRessource(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value="file", required=true) MultipartFile file){
    ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    String resultat = null;
    RessourceHome bean = (RessourceHome) ctx.getBean("RessourceHome");
    String titre = request.getParameter("titre");
    String description = request.getParameter("description");
    String fichierUpload = request.getParameter("file");
    String[] tagsRessource = request.getParameterValues("tagsRessource");
    String fichierName = file.getName();
    String fichierType = file.getContentType();

    try {
        byte[] bytes = fichierUpload.getBytes();
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("fichier")));
        stream.write(bytes);
        stream.close();            
        resultat = bean.ajouterRessource(titre, description, bytes, tagsRessource, fichierName, fichierType);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ModelAndView("creationRessource");
    }
    if (resultat == null) {
        String erreur = "Création de l'annonce réussie";            
        return new ModelAndView("creationRessource", "erreur", erreur);
    } else {        
        return new ModelAndView("creationRessource", "erreur", resultat);
    }       
}
```

My function "ajouterRessource" add the ressource to the database.
At the beginning, I don't know that the type MyltipartFile exists in Java. It works but I can't find the name and the content type of the file I'm uploading and save it in database.

Now, when I submit my form, I have an error :

```
janv. 06, 2016 7:08:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatchers] in context with path [/jobEISTI] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface] with root cause
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile]: Specified class is an interface
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.newCommandObject(MultiActionController.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.invokeNamedMethod(MultiActionController.java:466)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.multiaction.MultiActionController.handleRequestInternal(MultiActionController.java:408)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:900)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:874)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:790)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I don't have "jsp-api-*.jar" in my /WEB-INF/lib.
I think it comes from the MultipartFile but I don't know what I'm supposed to do. Please, could you help me ?

Thanks you a lot

Comment: Why are you using the outdated `MultiActionController`? Use a `@Controller` annotated type.

Comment: "I do not use Maven" - it's the root cause.

Comment: Please don't tell me you are actually writing code like this? Never create an instance of the application context to retrieve beans (well unless you want to run into out-of-memory issues, strange transaction issues, database starvation etc.). Use dependency injection to get needed services. You are also seem to mix different strategies (`@Controller` judging by the annotations) and the old `MultiActionController`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, When I began this project, I was thinking it was good, but it seems not, for my future projet, I will use [tag:@Controller] annotation from the beginning. 

To M. Deinum, I'm actually writing code like this, I have done a great misunderstood at the beginning of my project, it is the first project in JEE I have to do, for my next projects, I will apply all your advices : only annotations, use Maven and forget about MultiActionController.

I will try to update my Controller (remove MultiActionController and use annotations, I hope it's not too late
Thanks for your answers